# Remove spaces for header and footer from generated pdf IText 7 C#

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

Is there any easy way to remove the blank space for Header and Footer from my `PdfDocument` using `C#`? I believe it would be easier to remove it and just use the page content...

This is part of my code:

```
 PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);            
        pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);            
            PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDocument);

        foreach (var html in htmlPages)
        {
            MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
            PdfDocument temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));
            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, temp, properties);
            ReaderProperties rp = new ReaderProperties();
            baos = new MemoryStream(baos.ToArray());
            temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(baos, rp));
            merger.Merge(temp, 1, temp.GetNumberOfPages());
            temp.Close();
        }
        merger.Close();
        pdfDocument.Close();
```

**UPDATE**

To be more clear, I need a green sidebar that goes to the top and the bottom, and I want different content on every page where the header and footer suppose to go.. programmatically it would be way easier just to remove that margin and fill it out with page content than have to deal with headers and footers by separate...
[image]

Comment: You mean you want to remove the margins?

Comment: @mkl Yes I do, I updated my question so you can have a clearer idea of the issue..

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970902/1729265).

Comment: @mkl That is the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much!